# Issue storing/restoring a global string array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I am working through a course to learn swift. As part of a particular projects approach, I create a global string array called "tasks".

```
import UIKit

var tasks = [String]()
```

I have met the requirements for the project already, but now what I want to do is make that array permanent between app openings/closings. The method described in the course thus far is to use

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tasks, forKey: "array")
}
```

This should save the array. The problem comes in when I try to recall the array.

I've tried both of these methods inside viewDidLoad():

```
tasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("array")! as! NSArray
```

and

```
let returnedArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("array")! as! NSArray
        for i in returnedArray{
            tasks.append(returnedArray[i])
}
```

The first gives the error "NSArray is not convertible to '[String]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?"

The second gives the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') to expected argument type 'Int'.

Can anyone provide some guidance on what is going on? I am still a relative newbie (only been taking the course for about 2 weeks) and a lot of the documentation is too dense for me to understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first

```
// tasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("array")! as! NSArray
tasks = defaults.objectForKey("array") as? [String] ?? [String]()
```

Ref: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Hello, I have tried it but receive the error:
'NSArray!' is not convertible to '[String']; did you mean to downcast

Comment: This no longer gives me errors! However, it doesn't seem to be storing the array. I'll keep working on it!

Comment: Maybe you can try the link i give.

Comment: Yup, I've given it a shot. I'm going to keep working at it. :-)

Comment: I figured it out! I wasn't updating NSUserDefaults when I was actually adding items, rather I had the function under viewDidLoad. It works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a global variable containing a mutable (collection) type is not good programming habit due to data encapsulation.

Just in Swift there are much better solutions for example a static `struct`

```
struct Task {

  static var tasks = [String]()

  static func register()
  {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults( ["tasks" : [String]()])
  }

  static func load()
  {
    Task.tasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("tasks") as! [String]
  }

  static func save()
  {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Task.tasks, forKey:"tasks")
  }

  static func append(string : String)
  {
    Task.tasks.append(string)
  }
}
```

---

In `AppDelegate` as soon as possible call

```
Task.register()
```

to define a default value when the array has been never written to disk.

---

The methods

```
Task.load()
Task.save()
```

read and write the array from/to disk.

---

To append strings to the array use

```
Task.append("Hello")
Task.append("World")
```

---

And to get the values

```
print(Task.tasks) // ["Hello", "World"]
```

The static struct, declare outside any class, is accessible from everywhere and data encapsulation is ensured.

You can extend the struct by writing additional functions.
All functions need to be static functions and be called by `Task.<functionName>()`

Comment: I appreciate that it's not good style, however I am following/trying to keep within what knowledge I'm *supposed to have* at this point in the course. I will certainly keep track of your comment though so I know how to do it in the future. Thank you!

Comment: LOL! It's a well regarded course, but it only covers the basics. I fully expect to get better acquainted with proper "swift"isms as my knowledge base grows :-)

Comment: I would like to replace nsuserdefaults with something else, because the data set can bevond quit big

Comment: @alex Take a look at Core Data

Comment: @vadian tx will do that as soon as i get my simple code working. Could you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368563/swift-getting-struct-to-work-in-my-first-view-controller