# Swift getting struct to work in my first view controller?

Tags: ios, struct, uiviewcontroller

I am getting into using struct and now i am stuck on the first VC, it works as i expect in another VC. Here's what i have in my first VC (should i have struct in a seperate file?)

I need to use the lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance to populate a tableview in my first VC (other VC seems to work)

```
    struct ListVisitors{
    static var sharedInstance = [Visitor]()

    static func register()
    {
        //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults( ["tasks" : [String]()])
    }

    static func load()
    {
        //Task.tasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("tasks") as! [String]
    }

    static func save()
    {
        //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Task.tasks, forKey:"tasks")
    }

    static func append(visitor : Visitor)
    {
        //Task.tasks.append(string)
         ListVisitors.sharedInstance.append(visitor)
    }

}

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
```

Now the part which doesn't work in first VC but does seem to work in the other VC

First VC return Global 0

```
let lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // global testing
        self.testPopulateData()       
        print("Global \(lVisitors.count)")
```

func testPopulateData adds some test data to the ListVisitors.sharedInstance

Other VC returns test4

```
let lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        

        print(" test\(lVisitors.count)")
    }
```

[EDIT]
In my first VC, Within a func var ListVisitors.sharedInstance seems to have values, like

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance //shouldn't have to

    print("Row Global \(lVisitors.count)")
    return scannedVisitors.count //other test way
}
```

[EDIT 2]
I think i came up with a workable solution (tx @vadian and @Entalpi)

I added the testPopulateData function into my custom class and renamed it load() (in the future i like to replace this with a webservice file). And in my first VC after declaring an instance variable

```
var lVisitors = [Visitor]()
```

i added the followin in viewDidLoad()

```
ListVisitors.load()
  lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance
```

[EDIT 3] This class seems to work but @vadian recommends a singleton, so how do i rewrite this class into a singleton?

```
class ListVisitors{
static var sharedInstance = [Visitor]()
```

//    init(sharedInstance:Visitor){
//        self.sharedInstance = sharedInstance
//    }

```
static func register()
{
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults( ["tasks" : [String]()])

}

static func load()
{
    //Task.tasks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("tasks") as! [String]
    var visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class Matt", visitorCompany: "Google", visitorPlace: "San Diego", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "matt@google.com")
    sharedInstance = [visitor]

    visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class John", visitorCompany: "nike", visitorPlace: "New York", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "john@nike.com")
    //        ListVisitors.sharedInstance += [visitor]
    sharedInstance += [visitor]

    visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class Troy", visitorCompany: "nike", visitorPlace: "New York", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "troy@nike.com")
    //        ListVisitors.sharedInstance += [visitor]
    sharedInstance += [visitor]
    // append
    visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class Julian", visitorCompany: "leica", visitorPlace: "Tokyo", visitorPhone: "123411234", visitorEmail: "julian@shoot.co.jp")
    //        ListVisitors.append(visitor)
    sharedInstance.append(visitor)

}

static func save()
{
    //NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Task.tasks, forKey:"tasks")
}

static func append(visitor : Visitor)
{
    //Task.tasks.append(string)
    ListVisitors.sharedInstance.append(visitor)
}

static func delete(index: Int) {
    ListVisitors.sharedInstance.removeAtIndex(index)
    print("remove item")
}
```

}

Comment: You might retrieve the data (`ListVisitors.sharedInstance`) always in the function `viewDidLoad` rather than outside any function which could be too soon and unreliable.

Comment: @vadian when i retrieve the data in viewDidLoad i can't access the data in my tableview functions??

Comment: Of course I mean to declare an instance variable to save the array.

Comment: so something like this in another VC should work?  

`var lVisitors = [Visitor]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance
        
        print(" test \(lVisitors.count)")` but it returns test 0 (should be 3)

Comment: Maybe `viewDidLoad` is still too soon. Try it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: hmm, nope also returning 0 and not 3 (as in the first VC) i used `    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance
        print(" test view will appear\(lVisitors.count)")
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    }` any other func i could try?

Comment: Then use a singleton class rather than a struct due to the reference semantics of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with structs is that they are value types and thus are copied when you pass them around.

You are changing one copy of the struct in one VC and the other VC sits with a different copy and cannot see the changes made to the first VC's copy of the struct.

Comment: hhhmm, don't really understand what you mean, but how can i create a variable which can be access and updated by different VC's. Also i don't understand why defining let lVisitors = ListVisitors.sharedInstance outside the functions doesn't work in the first VC.

 I thought i could use struct like a "global" which could be access by different VC's.  I created a custom class Visitor and the struct would be VisitorList, where visitors are add/deleted.

Comment: ps i tried to follow this answer suggestion by vadian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303877/issue-storing-restoring-a-global-string-array-in-swift
reread your answer and i was thinking is there a way i could not copy the struct but use the same?

Comment: ps2: would just replacing the struct with a class solve my problem as the underlying data is the same in both VC's, right? that's value vs reference difference?

Comment: Yup! That's it mate! :) The problem was that with the struct each VC got a copy. Then when you changed one copy the other ones does not change. 

The class gave you a reference and when you change via a reference the real deal gets changed and thus both the VCs see the changes. :)